# Dissolve polygons for each column in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, dissolve

I am wondering if there is a way to repeat the dissolve process for each column in order to have just one shapefile as outcome. In the image an example of input data and desired outcome.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the result you want but if you leave all the Dissolve_Fields unchecked and check Create multipart features you will end up with only one feature.

[image]